# Get last access time of the file?

Tags: python, file, inode

I want to get when the file  accessed last time, I tried following code:

```
import os, time

os.system("python test.py")
print os.stat('test.py').st_atime

time.sleep(60)

os.system("python test.py")
print os.stat('test.py').st_atime
```

But each time the output is same as follows :

```
1358489344.72
1358489344.72
```

I was expecting a difference in output before delay and after delay.
also output is same wen I run the code every time.

what could be wrong?

Comment: Do you access the file between the interval?

Comment: I think it may be that access time in unix updated on read(2) calls, not updated when files are read via mmap(2)

Comment: Import os.path and then print lastmodified and created see question 237079

Comment: @RachelGallen modified/created != accessed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The field st_atime is changed by file accesses, for example, by execve(2), mknod(2), pipe(2), utime(2) and read(2) (of more than zero bytes). Other routines, like mmap(2), may or may not update st_atime.

While you run "python test.py", it won't call read(2), instead it would call mmap(2). That's why the access time didn't be udpated.

Here is output of "strace python test.py"

```
open("test.py", O_RDONLY)               = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=36, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 65536, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2ad626cdd000
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the filesystem is mounted with `noatime` option

```
noatime
     Do not update inode access times on this filesystem 
     (e.g, for faster access on the news spool to speed up news servers).
```

check your `/etc/fstab`

More about access time https://superuser.com/questions/464290/why-is-cat-not-changing-the-access-time