# alternative to getatime to find last file access in python

Tags: python

I am trying to see how many times some of the installed applications are being used on a system.

I used in my python script

```
fileaccesstime=os.path.getatime(os.sep.join([dirpath, filename]))
```

Some of the applications dont seem to update atime even when accessed. For example, I used python and saw that atime did not change.

From [Get last access time of the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393744/get-last-access-time-of-the-file) it appears that atime might not get updated because it would call mmap.

Does that mean I can never find the last access time. I am unsure how to proceed to find out the last access for some applications eg. python

Comment: An application does not update atime, the OS does (or doesn't). For example, a Unix file system mounted with `noatime` option will never update atime. This is often done because updating atime actually converts a read operation to a write operation. So atime is generally not reliable unless you have the opportunity to change the mount options.

Answer (score 0):

You should check this way:

```
import os, time
print time.ctime(os.stat('my_path/test.txt').st_atime)
```

**OR**

```
(mode, ino, dev, nlink, uid, gid, size, atime, mtime, ctime) = os.stat(file)
print "Last Access: %s" % time.ctime(atime)
```

I recommend you to check official info at [`os.stat()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat):

*To check **creation&modification** dates*

```
print "Modification Date: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(file))
print "Creation Date: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getctime(file))
```

**OR**

```
(mode, ino, dev, nlink, uid, gid, size, atime, mtime, ctime) = os.stat(file)
print "Modification Date: %s" % time.ctime(mtime)
print "Creation Date: %s" % time.ctime(ctime)
```