# python delete files no one accessed in x days

Tags: python, file-io, filesystems

I wish to write a python script which deletes files which weren't accessed in >= x days.
I know I can check when the file was created and when it was modified, but can I somehow check when it was last accessed ?

Thanks,
Li

Comment: Check here for how to get the "last access time" of a file:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393744/get-last-access-time-of-the-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check when the file was last opened using 'stat',
Check how much time has passed using 'time',
And delete it using 'os':

```
import os
import stat
import time

fileStats = os.stat(filePath)
last_access = fileStats[stat.ST_ATIME] # in seconds
now = time.time() # in seconds
days = (now - last_access)  / (60 * 60 * 24) 
# The seconds that have elapsed since the file was last opened are divided by the number of seconds per day 
# this give the number of days that have past since the file last open

if x <= days:
  # we delete the file
    os.remove(filePath)
```